# Как прочитать содержимое страницы и если в тексте встречаются две точки подряд- оставить только одну?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть span-ы, в них текст с двумя точками в конце некоторых предложений (..)
Как перебрать все span и убрать лишнюю точку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('span'),
  (s) => s.textContent = s.textContent.replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.')
)
```

```html
<span>aaa..</span>
<span>ttt..</span>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное! А если такая последовательность (,.)- как убрать точку?

Comment: @АнтонБогданов `(/,\./g, ',')` - читай регулярные выражения